# Downloading files with node.js, streams, and promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, promise, bluebird

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var processListing = function (directoryItems) {
    console.log('foreach');
    var itemsToDownload = [];
    directoryItems.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
        //Ignore directories
        if (element.type === 'd') {
            console.log('directory ' + element.name);
            return;
        }
        //Ignore non zips
        if (path.extname(element.name) !== '.zip') {
            console.log('ignoring ' + element.name);
            return;
        }
        //Download zip
        itemsToDownload.push({
            source: element.name,
            destination: element.name
        });
        //aftpSystem.downloadFile(element.name, element.name);
    });
    console.log('after foreach');
    return itemsToDownload;
};

var getFiles = function () {
    console.log('got files');
    return fs.readdirAsync(process.cwd() + "/zips/").then(function (files) {
        return files.filter(function (filename) {
            return path.extname(filename) === '.zip';
        });
    });
};

    aFtpClient. //this has been promisified
    listAsync(). //so calls methodAsync
    then(processListing).
    map(function (object) {
        return processItem(object).then(function (processResult) {
            return {
                input: object,
                result: processResult
            };
        });
    }).
    map(function (downloadItem) {
        console.log('downloading files');

        downloadItem.result.once('close', function () {
            console.log('closed');
        });

        return downloadItem.result.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(process.cwd() + "/zips/" + downloadItem.input.destination));
    }).
    then(getFiles).
```

I'm trying to use promises to download items via FTP. At the moment it downloads the first file but then fails on subsequent files. I'm new to node but fairly confident that my second map function needs to return a promise however I have been unable to work out how after numerous attempts.  I am using `bluebird` for promises but can't see how to work with it and streams.

Could you point me in the correct direction?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're returning a stream where you actually wanted to return a promise.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I put that in the question but not sure how to do that with a stream

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure where exactly you're stuck but pointing you in the general direction should suffice:

- You have an interface that works with a pipe and events
- You need to **promisify** that interface.

So what you need to do is:

1. Find out what's the 'completion' event of the download.
2. Create a promise and resolve it on that event, reject it on the failed event.
3. Return that promise.

Promisifying can be done in several ways:

- By the promise library. Bluebird contains a really clever promisifier using dynamic code generation that relies on the JIT - it is *very* fast - but it's built for the NodeJS "nodeback" case. (i.e. error passed as first argument of the callback.)
- Using the `Deferred` object. Generally that way is more error prone.
- Using `Promise.method` in Bluebird, which is great for promisifying APIs easily but is not really our case here.
- Using the `Promise` constructor. This is what we'll do here. It's also standards complaint.

Generally, the interface of the promise constructor is:

```
new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

    resolve(); // this resolves the promise
    reject(); // this rejets the promise
});
```

Note, promisifying event emitters only works well *when they fire on a finish event and do so once*. Promises are one time, once they settle they can't change state. Events can fire multiple times. It's perfectly fine to promisify things like `"load"` events or `"finished"` events - but don't promisify things that repeat multiple times.

Your second map should be something like:

```
map(function (downloadItem) {
    console.log('downloading files');

    downloadItem.result.once('close', function () {
        console.log('closed');
    });
    var pipeAction = downloadItem.result.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(process.cwd() + "/zips/" + downloadItem.input.destination));
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        pipeAction.on("end",function(){ //waits for data to be consumed
             // pipe has ended here, so we resolve the promise
             resolve();
        });
    });
}).
```

You should generally extract promisifications into dedicated methods. For example, the above could be a `promisifyPipe` or similar.

Comment: Wow! This a great answer and really appreciate it and I will take a lot away from it. Unfortunately its still not downloading properly but most likely my noob code. Have updated my question with full code

Comment: I added code to your "end" event to log out but it never gets there. I tried adding {end: false} to the pipe too

Comment: Hmm, what about the close event? Not all streams fire `"end"` and I'm unsure what interface exactly you're using..

Comment: I'm using this https://www.npmjs.org/package/ftp Looks like the close event will work

Comment: I think your code needs to be `resolve,reject`. It now fires in that function but only once. not multiple times if multiple files to download

Comment: oh yeah, my bad, so used to automatic promisification and request handlers :) Good catch.

Comment: @Esailija I thought about it but that way I would not be able to put the comment as easily in the code ;)

Comment: hmm, something odd going on with this downloading..only manages 1 file

Comment: @Jon If you put a log inside the event handler - does it only log once? Also, does the returned mapping contain the correct elements?

Comment: no the event of close is called twice (I have 2 files). My getFiles function doesnt do anything with the result of the map. It just reads the files in the dir, hopefully where they have downloaded to

Comment: i added getFiles to the question

Comment: changing the getFiles to accept a parameter and logging it, it shows [undefined,undefined]

Comment: actually sometimes its logged once, sometimes twice :s

Comment: I'm going to mark it as answered, thanks for your help but I'm still stuck on why it only downloads one at a time.

Comment: This answer was too generic. When dealing with streams what are the "hook" methods to declare the promise.resolve, and promise.reject methods in to ensure that all cases are covered? The "end" event might be correct here. (for example, some "close" events then call "end" etc. Some clarifications would be welcome. The promise specific description stuff is easy.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a promisified pipe:

```
//example: promisified_pipe(foo, fs.createWriteStream(somepath))enter code here
function promisified_pipe(response, file) {
let ended = false;

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    response.pipe(file);

    function nice_ending() {
      if (!ended) {
        ended = true;
        resolve();
      }
    }

    function error_ending() {
      if (!ended) {
        ended = true;
        reject("file error");
      }
    }

    file.on('finish', nice_ending);
    file.on('end', nice_ending);
    file.on('error', error_ending);
    file.on('close', error_ending);
  }).finally(() => file.close())
}
```